# How to Format a datetime to String as "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'" format in python

Tags: python, datetime, format, iso8601, rfc3339

I want to get datetime.now but in like this format "2023-11-13T02:12:01.480Z"
I have try to using

```
 now = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%Z")
```

but get :

```
2023-11-15T08:27:34.
```

How to Format a datetime to String as  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'"  format in python
any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the `Z` as indicating zulu time or just a literal Z? Why do you use `.%Z` when you want neither a dot nor the actual timezone? Is `now` under your control and/or always the current time, or do you have to deal with arbitrary datetimes?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi a literal Z ***not*** indicating UTC would be very misleading in this context, imho. Your point regarding arbitrary datetime is good; the time zone might not be set, conversion to UTC therefore ambiguous, and the 'Z' suffix potentially incorrect. If a time zone is set other than UTC, a [conversion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) before formatting to string would be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR use

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone

datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec="milliseconds").replace("+00:00", "Z")
# '2023-11-15T07:18:11.226Z'
```

NOTE you need to specify UTC as tz argument to *actually get* UTC datetime instead of local time from `datetime.now`.

---

***aware datetime object as input***

```py
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
now = datetime.now(ZoneInfo("Europe/Berlin")) # UTC+1 in Nov 2023
now
# datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 15, 11, 57, 27, 899158, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Berlin'))

now.astimezone(timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec="milliseconds").replace("+00:00", "Z")
# '2023-11-15T10:57:27.899Z'
```

***naive datetime as input***

```py
now = datetime.now() # local time !
now
# datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 15, 11, 59, 52, 263956)

# NOTE input stays local time, no Z added:
now.isoformat(timespec="milliseconds").replace("+00:00", "Z")
# '2023-11-15T11:59:52.263'

# NOTE input *assumed* to be local time, then converted to UTC,
#      therefore the Z is added:
now.astimezone(timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec="milliseconds").replace("+00:00", "Z")
# '2023-11-15T10:59:52.263Z'
```